# Create two dictionaries from one single iterator

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, iterator

I need to create two dictionaries while reading input from one generator. I am concerned with the fact that both `dict` and the data only need to be scrolled once in principle. How should I proceed?

```
# dummy data
def data():
    yield 'a', 5
    yield 'b', 8
    yield 'c', 12

# two iterations, bad.
first  = {k: v + 1 for k, v in data()}
second = {k: 2 * v for k, v in data()}

# One iteration only, but it scans both dicts on each step?
first  = {}
second = {}
for k, v in data():
    first[k]  = v # this needs an underlying iteration over `first`, right?
    second[k] = v # and this needs another underlying iteration over `second`..

# Is there aa.. multiple comprehension?
first, second = {k: v + 1, k: 2 * v for k, v in data()} # SyntaxError
# Would it be just equivalent to the previous loop?
```

Comment: What do you mean by "this needs an underlying iteration over `first`"? Dicts don't require iteration to assign a new item, it's an O(1) operation.

Comment: The second version is better, but there's no benefit for one single comprehension, assuming it's even possible. Just use two dict comprehensions.

Comment: The complexity is 2O(n) which is still O(n). There is no marked difference between the two if you are thinking in terms of speed and complexity.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Well, I did not know that. How can it be? :)

Comment: @joydeepbhattacharjee Well, in practice, 2O(n) is still twice the time :P

Comment: @iago-lito technically yes, but in general practice this is meaningless. you will always be more interested in how the program scales.

Comment: @joydeepbhattacharjee Mmh.. I would say yes if I were a very general framework developper, or a researcher in algorithmics. But as a scientist data-cruncher, if it takes 1 day to scroll through my genomic `data`, I do mind not taking 2 days for the same task :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your 2nd approach is probably the best way, adding a key to a `dict` does not need an underlying iteration over that `dict`. In fact the time complexity it simply O(1), i.e. constant time, and independent of the dictionary size.

Comment: Shouldn't that be O(1)?

Comment: Amazing! How can it be? Ô.Ô Good news anyway, thanks :)

Comment: @Chris_Rands Is O(1) not called *constant* time where *linear* time is O(n)? õ.Ô

Comment: @iago-lito Also note that `dict` comprehensions has some optimizations over a `for` loop and there may be some cases where doing 2 comprehensions is actually still faster. It's hard to know this *a priori*, you you'll need to test this on your data if performance is critical